# How can I count number of rows returned by a join in Slick?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, slick

When I try to do `Query(query.length).first` on a query, that represents a join of 2 tables which have several columns with the same names, I am getting malformed sql. Consider the example:

```
// in Main.scala
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
object Main extends App {

  object Houses extends Table[Long]("Houses") {
    def id = column[Long]("id")
    def * = id
  }
  object Rooms extends Table[(Long, Long)]("Rooms") {
    def id = column[Long]("id")
    def houseId = column[Long]("houseId")
    def * = id ~ houseId
  }

  val query = for {
    h <- Houses
    r <- Rooms
    if h.id === r.houseId
  } yield (h, r)
  println("QUERY: " + Query(query.length).selectStatement)
}

// in build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "1.0.1"
```

This example generates the following SQL:

```
select x2.x3 from
  (select count(1) as x3 from 
    (select x4.`id`, x5.`id`, x5.`houseId` 
     from `Houses` x4, `Rooms` x5 where x4.`id` = x5.`houseId`) x6) x2
```

Which is clearly wrong and is rejected by MySQL because `id` column is duplicated in `select x4.id, x5.id` part.

I could try to do the following:

```
query.list.size
```

but that will extract all the rows from the query and send them over the wire, which is going to hinder performance greatly.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some way to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an interesting issue.  Usually with SQL, you alias the other column which would cause a name collision but I'm not sure how that works with Slick (or if even possible).  But you can work around this I believe by only selecting a single column if you just want to count:

```
val query = for {
  h <- Houses
  r <- Rooms
  if h.id === r.houseId
} yield h.id.count
```

Now the `count` call on `id` is deprecated, but this one produced a clean sql statement which looks like this:

```
select count(x2.`id`) from `Houses` x2, `Rooms` x3 where x2.`id` = x3.`houseId`
```

Anything that I tried using `.length` produced a bunch of sql that was not correct.

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, it you wanted to leave the query the way it was (and let's forget that the query itself is broken due to field collision/ambiguity in the join) and then be able to also derive a count query from it, that would look like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val query = for {
    h <- Houses
    r <- Rooms
    if h.id === r.houseId
  } yield (h,r)

  val lengthQuery = query.map(_._1.id.count)
}
```

The point here is that you should be able to take any query and `map` it to a count query by selecting a single column (instead of the full objects) and then getting that `count` for that column.  In this case, because the result is a `Tuple2`, I have to go in an additional level to get to the `id` column, but I think you get the picture.

Comment: That works, indeed. I hoped that there exists a solution for general `Query[A,B]` case, because that would reduce the cruft in the code (current solution will require me to hand-write counting code for every query). But since I don't see how the general solution can be possible, this is the only way.

Comment: @Rogach, I added more detail to the answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks! But I meant a different thing. For example, I have a helper method `runApiQuery[A,B](query: Query[A,B])`, that gets stuff from query, applies limits, counts query objects, etc. If the `.length` on Query worked properly, I just could do `query.length` inside the method, without adding burden to `runApiQuery` caller (and since Slick team haven't commented on the bug for 6 days already, that probably wouldn't happen soon). In current situation, I only can add a parameter to runApiQuery: `runApiQuery[A,B,C](q: Query[A,B])(countCol: A => Column[C])` and use countCol later in the body.

Comment: Funny, I didn't read your whole comment and actually came up with basically the same method signature you did before looking at the comment again `def runApiQuery[A,B, C:BaseTypeMapper](query:Query[A,B])(f:(A) => Column[C])`.  The count needs a column to key in on so I'm not sure you can do better than this.  I'm not sure how Slick can even address this properly.  Let's say they select a column; how can they be sure it's the best column to count on?  You should always count on an indexed column so what if their logic occasionally results in counting on a non-indexed col?

Comment: They do `count(1)`, so the db decides what column to use - I hope that it decides right.